# word2vec is not defined (Julia)

Tags: nlp, julia, word2vec

I'm getting an error that prevents me from using the `word2vec` function in Julia on a corpus.

`Install.pkg("Word2Vec")`

Code:

```
using Word2Vec
word2vec("text8","vec.txt",verbose=true)
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: word2vec not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] word2vec(::String, ::String; size::Int64, window::Int64, sample::Float64, hs::Int64, negative::Int64, threads::Int64, iter::Int64, min_count::Int64, alpha::Float64, debug::Int644, binary::Int64, cbow::Int64, save_vocab::Nothing, read_vocab::Nothing, verbose::Bool) at C:\Users\15714\.julia\packages\Word2Vec\knfyL\src\interface.jl:73
 [2] top-level scope at none:1
```

Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature is correct and works for me on macOS with Julia 1.5.2. I am guessing that perhaps you are a Windows user and it looks like Windows is not supported. See here for details: https://github.com/JuliaText/Word2Vec.jl#installation

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there substitute library that you recommend?

Comment: You can potentially just use Embeddings.jl if you just want pretrained embeddings

Answer (score 2):

the word2vec function is available only on linux and OS X.